# How to hide firmware logo in GRUB?

Tags: fedora, grub2, uefi, framebuffer

I [disabled the hidden menu feature](https://hansdegoede.livejournal.com/19081.html) of GRUB on Fedora 34 Workstation, which hides GRUB menu and lets the vendor logo remain on the screen during GRUB operation.

```
$ sudo grub2-editenv - unset menu_auto_hide
```

If I set `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE` to `countdown` or `hidden`, the vendor logo again remains on the screen until GRUB boots the default entry. For instance, with `countdown`, the countdown overtakes only a part of the screen, but the logo remains in the centre of the screen. If I set `GRUB_TIMEOUT` to `0` instead, the vendor logo also remains on the screen until GRUB boots the default entry.

How do I configure GRUB to overtake and refresh the whole screen?

With `menu_auto_hide` unset, `GRUB_TIMEOUT=1` overrides the logo, but shows the GRUB menu.

```
$ cat /etc/default/grub
GRUB_TIMEOUT=1
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rhgb quiet video=efifb:nobgrt fbcon=nodefer"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG=true
```